# How do you parse a nodejs entry that is labeled as zero?

Tags: node.js

I am processing a javascript object that labeled the entry as zero.   I want to get the size value.

```
   foo.getOrder({}, function(err, resp, obj) {
    console.log("get Order fuction");
    console.log("Start of Entries");
    console.log(Object.entries(obj));
    console.log("End of Entries");

   const parsedSize = JSON.parse(obj[0]);
   console.log(parsedSize);
   });
```

Here is what displays.

```
    get Order function
    Start of Entries

    [
      [
        '0',
        {
          id: '123abc',
          size: '0.0123',
          type: 'medium'
         }
       ]
    ]
```

I have tried

```
   const parsedSize = JSON.parse(obj[0]);
   console.log(parsedSize);
```

it returns undefined:1

thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: Trying to understand the two square brackets at the start of the list of the entries.  obj is the entire object.  So the first [ is that the zero element and the the second [ is the next element  thus it would be the 1 element? 
Like this   get Order function
    Start of Entries

    [
      [
        '0',
        {
          id: '123abc',
          size: '0.0123',
          type: 'medium'
         }
       ]
       [
        '1',
        {
          id: '456abc',
          size: '0.0321',
          type: 'large'
         }
       ]
    ]

Comment: Hi Paul  Thanks for your assistance.  I ended up using var arrayLength = obj.length;    Then I used a for loop from zero to < arrayLength.   This way I could iterate through the obj[i].size etc.